# Do the values of two reflective light filters arranged one behind the other add up in this way?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I've had a pair of sunglasses custom-made, in these glasses are (here simplified values) 2 filters (by reflection) for the wavelengths 400-455nm with an intensity reduction of 50% per filter each arranged behind each other (filter 1 consists of the front glasses coating, filter 2 is the lens material itself behind it).

But now I wonder, if the protection either adds up like this:

1. $I_{filtered} = I_{Absolute} * (0,5)^{2}$, so if the sun is viewed in the 400-455nm range with an (imaginary) absolute intensity of 1 through the filters, **25% ends up getting through?**
2. Or by the fact that between the filters is also reflection:

[image]

and we now imagine that while light is thrown back and forth between the filters, also new light is added again and again, and thus the values on the far right add up (infinite, converging geometric series) $0,25 + 0,0625 + ... = \frac{0,25}{1-0,25} = 1/3$ at the end **33.33% comes through?**

(In reality, I only know that filter 1 (i.e. the coating) is reflective (about 40%) and I was told that the tint behind it (my "filter 2") also absorbs and/or reflects some percentage. Now I wonder mathematically what the worst filter ratio between filter 1 & 2 could be?)

In the case that **Filter 1 reflects 1% and Filter 2 99%** (or the other way around, should be the same outcome?) is it numerically correct to say that in the **extreme case of absorption** 1%*99% = **0,99% comes through** and in the **extreme case of reflection** again sum of the infinite geometric series 9.9E-3 + 9.801E-5 + 9.70299E-7 + ... = $\frac{9,9E-3}{1-9,9E-3}$≈ **0,999899%**? So ultimately no matter what filter values (%) the 2 filters have, 2 behinde of each other are still more effective than just one?

Comment: What about absorption?

Comment: @Farcher already realised that I've made two extreme cases, see last text block in question. Absorption would be the best, reflection the baddest. In think in reality it's somewhere in between.

Comment: @Farcher Finally, I was annoyed because the sunglass production was not originally intended (it should be just one filter) and now I want to tell me at least nicely for the lost money that it filters a bit more  In fact, I only know that filter 1 (the coating) is reflective (about 40%) and I was told that the tint behind it also absorbs and/or reflects some percentage between 400-455nm... just wanted to rationalize that 2 behind of each other help more (no matter in which variations [percentage of Reflection, Absorption of each]).

Comment: Only you can decide if the filtering process means that too little light arrives at your eyes, ie the filters are too dense.

Comment: @Farcher Well, yes I find it better to filter more between 400-455nm.