# Can interference occur between two consecutively arranged light filters (via reflection) in the space between them?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, geometric-optics

(This is a follow up question from my previous one: [Do the values of two reflective light filters arranged one behind the other add up in this way?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782494/do-the-values-of-two-reflective-light-filters-arranged-one-behind-the-other-add))

[image]

The light of the imaginary intensity 1 is viewed through two consecutively arranged filters, each reflecting 50%.

(In the extreme case of pure reflection with continuous irradiation, it is observed that the sum of intensities of the infinite converging geometric series, I_filtered = 0.25 + 0.0625 + ... = $\frac{0.25}{1 - 0.25}$ = 33.33% reaches the eye [in the extreme case of pure absorption it's 50% * 50% = 25% so a slightly better performance, in reality I suppose the value is somewhere in between])

Is it possible for constructive and/or destructive interference to occur between these filters? My custom sunglasses have two consecutively arranged light filters, each reflecting a certain amount between 400-455nm, and it would be inconvenient if more intensity reached my eye in the end or just enough to make one filter useless due to amplifications because of constructive interference between them...

What would be the worst outcome (highest possible transmission to the eye sight) due to the effects of interference in a system like that?

Answer (score 0):

About interference effect:

Roughtly speaking: any observable effect occurs when light is interacting with matter, but not in the course of propagation.

To explain what I mean by that I start with an example.

Let there be a double slit setup, with observation of interference pattern as the light falls on a screen. Significantly, the material properties of the screen make a difference for how visible the arising interference pattern will be. A mirror for, example, would even prevent an interference pattern from being visible. You want to use a material that the light will significantly interact with. You do want some of the light to reflect from the screen, in order to see it, but it is necesary for that light to be *scattered*. That is, the light losing directional information goes toward observable interference pattern.

The general pattern is: it is when the light goes through some process that is *irreversible* that the conditions are in place for interference pattern to be *observable*.

Light negotiating a filter with a 50% probability of transmitting light is such an instance of irreversible process.

**Propagation of light**

Does interference of light also occur *during* propagation? Well, the problem with that question is: there is no way of observing that.

The simplest approach is to assume that during propagation nothing irreversable happens, so all possibilities remain available.

With an extremely high degree of probability: two beams of light will pass through each other with no interaction occuring.

The reason for 'high propability' rather than 'absolute certainty': probability of [photon-photon scattering](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2021/12/13/photon-photon-scattering/) is extremely low, but not zero.

Returning to the filters with 50% probability of transmitting the light:
It seems to me that it is sufficient to assume that only the interaction with the filters counts for eliciting interference effect - the interaction with the filters being the only irreversible process. It seems safe to assume that light from many directions can propagate through the same space without any observable effect arising from cross-propagation.